# What is wrong in this encrypt/dycrpt code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have made this encrypt dycrypt code , but isnt working due to some error when it reaches oddl[c] it showes Index error can anybody tell what i did worng in this code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox,simpledialog,Tk
def even(number):
    return number %2==0

def gevenl(message):
    evenl=[]
    for c in range(0,len(message)):
        if even(c):
            evenl.append(message[c])
        return evenl

def goddl(message):
    oddl=[]
    for c in range (0,len(message)):
        if not even(c):
            oddl.append(message[c])
        return oddl

def swap(message):
    letter=[]
    if not even(len(message)):
        message=message+"."
    evenl=gevenl(message)
    oddl=goddl(message)
    for c in range(0,int(len(message)/2)):
        letter.append(oddl[c])
        letter.append(evenl[c])
    newm="".join(letter)
    return newm

def gettask():
    task=simpledialog.askstring("","Encrypt or Decrypt?")
    return task
def getm():
    message=simpledialog.askstring("Message","Enter is secret message: ")
    return message
root=Tk()

while True:
    task=gettask()
    if task=="encrypt":
        message=getm()
        encrypted=swap(message)
        messagebox.showinfo(f"Encrypted message is:{encrypted}")
    elif task=="decrpyt":
        message=getm()
        dycrypted=swap(message)
        messagebox.showinfo(f"Dycrpted message is{dycrypted}")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Idiot","Ayo stupid baka, No breaking in hahaha")
        break
root.mainloop()

It is showing this error:
line 26, in swap
    letter.append(oddl[c])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but no matter how much I change it, I dosen't workPls tell what to fix

Comment: Way too much code that's not relevant to the problem. Try unit testing gevenl and goddl. Rhetorical question: What should I get from gevenl("0123456789")?

Comment: On a side note, consider better function names, and don't call your users stupid for typing in the exact options you gave them. :)

Comment: @PythonBasicsDev. Mine is working. I don't see any error. I got msg for u. "Idiot","Ayo stupid baka, No breaking in hahaha. That all I see dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent one level out the `return` statements in functions `goddl` and `gevenl`, otherwise the generated lists end up with just one element, throwing the `IndexError` when accessing their elements.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,But unfoutunatley,it's not working...

Comment: @PythonBasicsDev You've got a typo in `elif task=="decrpyt":` and messagebox.showinfo method takes in two arguments: title and message; you only provided the title.